# A name that witnesses an existential statement is forced?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

The following is a rather silly statement which I can neither prove nor refute.

> Let $M\in V\models\mathrm{ZFC}$ such that
>    $M$ is countable and transitive in $V$ and $M\models\mathrm{ZFC}$.
>   Suppose $\mathbb P$ is a poset in $M$ that we use for forcing.
>   If $p\in\mathbb P$ and $\varphi(\sigma,v)$ is a formula in the forcing language
>     such that $p\Vdash\exists v\ \varphi(\sigma,v)$,
>    then there is a $\mathbb P$-name $\tau\in M^{\mathbb P}$
>     such that $p\Vdash\varphi(\sigma,\tau)$.

I can (dis)prove the analogous statements for $\neg$, $\wedge$, $\vee$, $\rightarrow$ and $\forall$, but for some reason, this one seems to be much harder than the others.

I expect this statement to be false, but I managed to find names that witness whatever existential formulas I came up with.

If the statement quoted above turns out to be true, then how would one prove it?  If the statement is false, then is there a simple counterexample in which the poset $\mathbb P$ is Cohen's?

Comment: when you write $p\Vdash\psi$, you really mean that $M\models p\Vdash\psi$, right?

Comment: @Andres: Yes, but I suppose I can also interpret it as $V\models p\Vdash\psi$, can't I? I thought they are the same  (when defined appropriately), and so I didn't bother to specify the model. Sorry, I am sometimes not aware that my notation is non-standard/ambiguous.

Comment: (Lawrence, in general, the two statements are different. $M$ and $V$ (or just about any two distinct models) may disagree about what a poset forces. Sometimes people write $\Vdash_M$ to indicate that the forcing relation is interpreted in the sense of $M$.)

Comment: @Andres: Yes, I see what you mean now. Thank you very much for pointing it out, which helped make my understanding clearer. When I wrote for myself, the symbol $\Vdash$ means two different things when interpreted in $V$ and in $M$ (more specifically, I used to drop the $^*$ on $\Vdash^*$ in the notation of Kunen's book), which was a little stupid because it confused myself at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. This is called **the mixing lemma**, or **the maximum principle**.

The way to prove it is to see that the definition of $p\vDash\exists\tau\varphi$ is that there exists a set which is dense below $p$ such that for every $q$ in that set there exists a name $\tau_q$ for which $q\vDash\varphi(\sigma,\tau_q)$. We may assume that if $(q',\tau')\in\tau_q$ then $q'\leq q$.

Now conclude that there exists $C$ which is a maximal (below $p$) antichain of such conditions, and take the name $\tau=\bigcup_{q\in C}\tau_q$. Show that $\tau$ is the name you seek.

Interesting to point out, this principle is equivalent to the axiom of choice in $\sf ZF$.

Comment: Thank you, Asaf!  With your information, I can now find the statement in Kunen's book.  The proof there is a little different from yours, and I still wish to see how your argument works.  I am stuck when I wish to show that: if $G$ is an $M$-generic filter containing $p$, and $q$ is the unique element in $C\cap G$, then $\mathrm{val}(\pi,G)\in\mathrm{val}(\tau,G)$ implies $\mathrm{val}(\pi,G)\in\mathrm{val}(\tau_q,G)$.  Am I proving the wrong thing again?

Comment: Lawrence, you indeed want to show that. The proof is easier using Boolean valued models.

Comment: I still don't see how this can be true. For example, pick $a,b\in M$ such that $a\not=a\cup b\not=b$. We know $p\Vdash\exists v\ (v=\check a\vee v=\check b)$ for any condition $p$. We can take some $\tau_q$'s to be $\check a$ and other $\tau_q$'s to be $\check b$, but then your $\tau$ always evaluates to $a\cup b$ in a forcing extension, which does not witness our existential statement. Am I missing something?

Comment: Lawrence, I was just about to edit this into the answer. We can choose $\tau_q$ to be a name such that whenever $(r,\tau')\in\tau_q$ then we have $r\leq q$. Now the result should be immediate.

Comment: Thank you very much, Asaf. I now see how your proof works. Although this argument is nice and simple, the lemma is still a little unexpected for a beginner like me.

Comment: Yes. This lemma is quite unexpected, but simple and *very* useful. This is one of the few deep connections between forcing and the axiom of choice. (Generally we can do forcing without assuming choice, but a lot of the combinatorial properties we use stop working, and it becomes much harder.)